# How to "git stash" in RTC?

Tags: rational-team-concert

I need to stash some changes in Rational Team Concert, but have not found a way to do so.

Is there anything like git stash in Rational Team Concert?

ps: It was easier to ask a simple question in SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have the RTC command line client installed, or just the Eclipse client? You need one of the two.

Here is the documentation for the CLI:
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/rational-team-concert-command-line-reference/index.html

Git Stash is similar to Suspend a change set in RTC:

```
changeset suspend
```

Comment: I use the eclipse client, but may also use the command line. I tested it before.

Comment: For the Eclipse client, as long as you have loaded a repository workspace (which is your local sandbox on your computer), you can do a check in. That copies changes to the server from your local disk. Then, you can **Suspend** the change set. That saves it for later, just like a git stash.

Comment: And the `changeset resume` is similar to a `git stash apply`, right?

Comment: Yes, changeset resume is just like git stash apply.